# Android Studio: Simulating increment and decrement of speed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-things

I'm in the process of developing an app that uses GPS to calculate speed in MPH, and then uses that speed to perform various tasks. The main task is accelerating above a specific speed in order to trigger certain events. Other events are triggered at specific speeds after the speed as gone above a certain amount.

Unfortunately, this requires me to go out in a car each time I want to test the app. What would be the best way to simulate acceleration and deceleration through Android Studio?

Comment: Use [fake GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en) app to simulate GPS based activities

Comment: @RutvikBhatt It does have a "random movement" feature but it doesn't seem to work well for retrieving speeds.